# How can I install pyperclip on mac?

Tags: python

```
Yangs-iMac:~ yangxu$ sudo pip install pyperclip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/Users/yangxu/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.8.2)
Yangs-iMac:~ yangxu$ sudo pip -H install pyperclip

Usage:   
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: -H
```

Comment: Do __not__ install Python packages with `sudo`. Also, do not use Python 2.

Comment: `pip install pyclip`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the error says, `Python 2.7` is deprecated. I would suggest that you upgrade your python version.

Second the error states that `pyperclip` is already installed. So no need to install it again.

Third, do not install python packages with `sudo`.

Finally, `pyperclip` has now changed to [pyclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/).